# JavaScript MadLib game - cannot call function on submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to complete a simple exercise to test my JavaScript skills at processing input elements from a form. The object of the game is to retrieve current values from the form input elements, make a story from them, and output that story in the 'story' div. However, when I click the 'Lib It!' button, the function is not getting called, and the text is not being replaced. Any ideas as to why this is not happening?

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title></title>
 </head>
 <body>

 <h1>Mad Libs</h1>

 <ul>
  <li>Noun: <input type="text" id="noun">
  <li>Adjective: <input type="text" id="adjective">
  <li>Someone's Name: <input type="text" id="person">
 </ul>

 <button id="lib-button" onclick="makeMadLib">Lib it!</button>

 <div id="story">Placeholder Text</div>

 <script type="text/javascript" src="exercises.js"></script>

 </body>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
    function makeMadLib(){
    var noun = document.getElementById("noun").value;
    var adjective = document.getElementById("adjective").value;
    var person = document.getElementById("person").value;


    var story = document.getElementById(story);



    story.firstChild.nodeValue = person + "likes taking photographs of" + adjective + noun;
}
```

Thanks,

Robert

London, Uk

Comment: Change : `onclick="makeMadLib"` to `onclick="makeMadLib()"`, forgot the parentheses. Also `...ntById("story");`. And I would do this for the story div tag: `document.getElementById(story).innerHTML = ... ;`

Answer (score 0):

First we forgot to use parentheses when calling the madLib function. Change `onclick="makeMadLib"` to `onclick="makeMadLib()"`. Then in our madlib function we need to add quotes around the `story` in `document.getElementById()` : `var story = document.getElementById("story");`. Finally to output our text all we have to do is use `innerHTML`.

**HTML**

```
...
<button id="lib-button" onclick="makeMadLib()">Lib it!</button>
...
```

**JS**

```
...

var story = document.getElementById("story");

....

story.innerHTML = person + " likes taking photographs of " + adjective + " " + noun;
```